Why does executing the entire command as a string result in weird behavior when the bubbletea view is being updated?
There is a section of my bubble tea model that I am using to place some text onto my clipboard. If the action is successful then it will show a message in the view that  has been copied.
copyToClipboardCommand := exec.Command("sh", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("echo %s | xclip -selection clipboard", m.results[m.selectedIndex].Login.Password))
copyToClipboardCommandOutput, err := copyToClipboardCommand.CombinedOutput()

The code below works as expected. My issue is why executing the shell command like above (in the copyToClipboard function) results in the view showing the previous m.message instead of the the one that should have been shown at the time of clicking ctrl+d. Also, when I click ctrl+d for the first time, a message is nt shown in the view even though the item appears in my clipboard.
Update section with just the "ctrl+d" part:
case "ctrl+d":
    switch m.State {
    case GetSearchInput:
       m.message = ""
       m.SearchError = nil
       return m, copyToClipboard(m)
       
    }

View section to display search results and any messages:
case 
GetSearchInput
:

    var b strings.Builder
    // Show results
    b.WriteString("Search: " + m.SearchInput.View() + "\n\n")

    if m.SearchError != nil {
       outputStrLen := len(m.searchCommandOutput)
       b.WriteString("Search Error: " + m.SearchError.Error() + "\n")

       if outputStrLen >= 10 {
          b.WriteString("First 10 characters of output: ")
          b.WriteString(m.searchCommandOutput[:10] + "\n\n")

          b.WriteString("Last 10 Characters of output: ")
          b.WriteString(m.searchCommandOutput[len(m.searchCommandOutput)-10:] + "\n\n")
       } else {
          b.WriteString("Output: " + m.searchCommandOutput + "\n\n")
       }

    }

    if m.SearchError == nil && m.message != "" {
       b.WriteString("Message: " + m.message + "\n\n")
    }

    // Show results with a highlight on the selected item
    if len(m.results) > 0 {
       b.WriteString("Results:\n")
       for i, result := range m.results {
          cursor := " " // no cursor by default
          if i == m.selectedIndex {
             cursor = ">" // show cursor for selected item
             b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s %s\n", cursor, result.Name))
          } else {
             b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("  %s\n", result.Name))
          }
       }
    } else {
       b.WriteString("No results\n")
    }

    return helpers.RenderBox(b.String(), "BitCustos")

copyToClipboard function to copy the password selected to the clipboard
func copyToClipboard(m VaultItemModel) tea.Cmd {

    return func() tea.Msg {

       copyToClipboardCommand := exec.Command("xclip", "-selection", "clipboard")
       copyToClipboardCommand.Stdin = strings.NewReader(m.results[m.selectedIndex].Login.Password)

       err := copyToClipboardCommand.Run()

       if err != nil {
          return ErrorMsg{
             error:       err,
             message:     "Failed to copy password to clipboard",
             returnState: CopyToClipboard,
          }
       }

       return SuccessMsg{
          stringValue: "Password for " + m.results[m.selectedIndex].Name + " was copied to the clipboard",
          returnState: CopyToClipboard,
       }

    }

}

